# gstreamer gst_element_seek very slow on mpeg2ts

Tags: c, gstreamer

Here is what I have come up with so far for seeking while playing:

```
case GDK_Up:
{

    gint64 pos_ns, dur_ns, seek_ns;
    GstFormat format;

    format = GST_FORMAT_TIME;

    gst_element_query_duration(pipeline,&format,&dur_ns);
    gst_element_query_position(pipeline,&format,&pos_ns);
    g_print ("Time: %" GST_TIME_FORMAT " / %" GST_TIME_FORMAT "\n", GST_TIME_ARGS (pos_ns), GST_TIME_ARGS (dur_ns));

    seek_ns = pos_ns + 60*GST_SECOND;

    if (!gst_element_seek (pipeline, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
             GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, seek_ns,
             GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE)) 
    {

        g_print ("Seek failed!\n");

    }


}

break;
```

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("filesrc location=filename.mpg ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! alsasink decoder. ! deinterlace ! ffmpegcolorspace ! glimagesink",&error);
```

The first seek will take about 3 seconds to perform, by the 5th or 6th seek it is taking 15 to 20 seconds to start playing from the new position.  I know I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out from the documentation what that is.

Is it the way I have constructed the pipeline?  I realize that I have taken some shortcuts here.

Is it the type of media file? (mpeg2ts) 
Is it the length of the media file? (4 hours)

The documentation says:

The application issues a seek on the pipeline and the new media is immediatly played after the seek calls returns.

So what is taking so long for the seek call to return?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is the debug log from a debug level of 2:

```
(fullscreen02:4554): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_property: property `device-name' of object class `GstAlsaSink' is not writable
0:00:01.137170699  4554       0x9d9500 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:754:gst_mpegts_demux_fill_stream: AC3 stream type found but no corresponding descriptor to differentiate between AC3 and EAC3. Assuming plain AC3.
0:00:01.179042694  4554       0x9d9500 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:754:gst_mpegts_demux_fill_stream: AC3 stream type found but no corresponding descriptor to differentiate between AC3 and EAC3. Assuming plain AC3.
0:00:01.188213891  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:01.188464979  4554 0x7ff9d80270e0 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
No accelerated IMDCT transform found
0:00:01.211118745  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN                    alsa gstalsa.c:124:gst_alsa_detect_formats:<alsasink0> skipping non-int format
No accelerated IMDCT transform found
0:00:01.237512648  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:832:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert0> downstream caps contain no channel layout
0:00:01.239176189  4554       0x9dabd0 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:832:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert0> downstream caps contain no channel layout
0:00:01.273765960  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN            audioconvert gstaudioconvert.c:832:gst_audio_convert_fixate_channels:<audioconvert0> downstream caps contain no channel layout
Got prepare-xwindow-id msg
0:00:01.326878070  4554       0x6068b0 WARN                 default xoverlay.c:354:gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id:<glimagesink0> Using deprecated gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()
0:00:01.326931302  4554       0x6068b0 WARN                 default xoverlay.c:390:gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle:<glimagesink0> Calling deprecated set_xwindow_id() method
0:00:01.337897164  4554 0x7ff9cc002cd0 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2380:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<pipeline0> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.000000000
0:00:02.042181425  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:03.016673305  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:04.489319920  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:05.961069736  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
Counter: 0:00:05.930250000 / 3:37:14.178723991  (this is when a 60 sec seek forward was initiated)
0:00:07.300999850  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:07.317269896  4554 0x7ff9cc005cd0 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2380:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<pipeline0> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.000000000
0:00:07.641986233  4554       0x9d9500 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin.c:1485:queue_filled_cb:<decoder> Queue is bigger than 20Mbytes, something else is going wrong
0:00:11.059481122  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:11.474393831  4554       0x9d9500 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin.c:1485:queue_filled_cb:<decoder> Queue is bigger than 20Mbytes, something else is going wrong
previous line repeated 55 times
0:00:12.532097973  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:12.538414925  4554       0x9d9500 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin.c:1485:queue_filled_cb:<decoder> Queue is bigger than 20Mbytes, something else is going wrong
previous line repeated 26 times
Counter: 0:02:05.745916667 / 3:37:14.178723991 (this is when a 60 sec seek forward was initiated)
0:00:13.113363951  4554 0x7ff9cc002c80 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2380:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<pipeline0> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.000000000
0:00:13.116343604  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:13.472504323  4554       0x9d9500 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin.c:1485:queue_filled_cb:<decoder> Queue is bigger than 20Mbytes, something else is going wrong
previous line repeated 9 times
0:00:25.545042104  4554 0x7ff9d8023c40 WARN             mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:2865:gst_mpegts_demux_src_pad_query:<mpegtsdemux0> unsupported query format or no bitrate yet to approximate duration from bytes
0:00:25.580215323  4554       0x9d9500 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin.c:1485:queue_filled_cb:<decoder> Queue is bigger than 20Mbytes, something else is going wrong
previous line repeated 43 times
```

I am currently in the process of looking up some of these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline looks okay. There have been lots of optimizations on mpegts elements. How up to date is your gstreamer installation. If your installation is up to date, you could run a profiler such as oprofile to see if there are hotspots. You can also check the gstreamer debug log to see if there are any complains regarding the file.

Comment: thank you for you help.  I'm using ver 0.10.35 which is the latest available in the gentoo repository.  I also set the debug level to 2 and put the output in the original question. I didn't get very far with oprofile, but I don't want to get off track.

Comment: Do you have intra pictures at regular intervals in the stream?

Comment: @user1559108 I don't know.  Is there a way to test for that?

Comment: If you have ffmpeg installed you can do a ffprobe -show_frames | grep pict_type | grep -n I   This will give you the location of each I picture. I am asking this because to seek ideally the framework needs I pictures. I would assume it seeks to the closest I picture then starts decoding from that point. If I pictures are far apart seek will take more time as there are more frames to decode to reach the exact seek point.