# gstreamer 1.0 seeking within an mpegts not working as expected

Tags: c, gstreamer, seek

I have a bunch of mpegts video files obtained from a Silicondust HDHomerun tuner.  Seeking was really slow in gstreamer 0.10 (see my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024019/gstreamer-gst-element-seek-very-slow-on-mpeg2ts)). Now seeking is greatly improved (in 1.0.6), but there are still problems.  Here is some stdout:

$ ./fullscreen02

```
No accelerated IMDCT transform found
No accelerated IMDCT transform found
pos_ns: 1700833333, seek_ns: 11700833333
position: 0:00:11.700833333

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed
Seek failed!
pos_ns: 1878166666, seek_ns: 11878166666
position: 0:00:11.878166666

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed
Seek failed!
pos_ns: 1468916666, seek_ns: 11468916666
position: 0:00:11.468916666

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed

(fullscreen02:30989): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_do_seek: assertion `segment->format == format' failed
Seek failed!
^C
```

As you can see pos_ns jumps around forward and back despite the fact that this is the output for three ten second skips forward as defined here:

```
        gint64 dur_ns, pos_ns, seek_ns;
        GstFormat format;

        format = GST_FORMAT_TIME;

        if ( !gst_element_query_position(pipeline,format,&pos_ns) )
            g_print("query position failed\n");

        seek_ns = pos_ns + 10*GST_SECOND;
        g_print ("pos_ns: %li, seek_ns: %li\n",pos_ns,seek_ns);
        g_print ("position: %" GST_TIME_FORMAT "\n", GST_TIME_ARGS (seek_ns));

        if ( !gst_element_seek_simple (pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT, seek_ns) ) 
          g_print ("Seek failed!\n");
```

You can also see in that same stdout that even though on screen the skip forward seems to be successful, gst_element_seek_simple is returning false and therefore complains that the seek failed.

I found a possibly related [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694369), but rather than wait for that patch to work through the system I thought I would be sure that I am not just doing something wrong.

Just a little extra information about the type of file:

$ ffmpeg -i EP00753796.0160_1357005474.67.mpg

```
[mpeg2video @ 0x629fa0] mpeg_decode_postinit() failure
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpegts @ 0x626320] PES packet size mismatch
Input #0, mpegts, from 'EP00753796.0160_1357005474.67.mpg':
  Duration: 00:29:59.69, start: 69837.938167, bitrate: 17997 kb/s
  Program 3 
    Stream #0:0[0x31]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 17000 kb/s, 30.43 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x34](eng): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s16, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x35](esl): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 192 kb/s (visual impaired)
```

And my pipeline:

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("filesrc location=EP00753796.0160_1357005474.67.mpg ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink decoder. ! deinterlace ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink",&error);
```

Although I get the same behavior using playbin within the same C program.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.